# How to fix dpdk build error: 'needs isa option -m32 -mssse3'

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build a dpdk application using dpdk v.18.08 on Centos 7.6 with gcc 7.3.1.

I have set:

```
$ echo $RTE_TARGET
x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
$ echo $RTE_SDK
/opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/
```

So my target is a 64-bit platform. But when I build my application I get error:

```
/opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_memcpy.h: In function ‘rte_memcpy_generic’:
/opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_memcpy.h:590:64: error: ‘__builtin_ia32_palignr128’ needs isa option -m32 -mssse3
         _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)((uint8_t *)dst + 0 * 16), _mm_alignr_epi8(xmm1, xmm0, offset));        \
```

Why does it want me to specify gcc option '-m32' when I am targeting a 64-bit platform?

Comment: have you used `make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc O=[path to your target/targetfolder]` to create the target folder RTE_TARGET? If yes, then cd `target folder` and running `make -j 10` should always use `SSE and AVX with -m64`. It looks like there is something different from the build steps. can you confirm?

Comment: I used usertools/dpdk_setup.sh option 15

Comment: Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                24

Comment: can you share the result of `lscpu | grep "Model name"`

Comment: Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6212U CPU @ 2.40GHz
I've built dpdk with gcc 4.8.5,  but built my application with gcc 7.3.1 (RedHat Dev Toolset 7), maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Hi David, I am not able to reproduce the issue with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with gcc 7.5.0

Comment: Hi @DavidA, can you help me understand when you have used `usertools/dpdk_setup.sh` how did it turn out to be `/opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/`. The default location is `opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/build/`. Can you please share the update.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Sorry, I have forgotten the details of this particular problem, and I have learnt a lot since!  I think the issue was with my compiler switches, which I managed to fix by copying those from the l2fwd example.